# How to find the first integer making two progressions have gcd $> 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm, linear-diophantine-equations

Is there a technique to efficiently find the first positive integer, $r$, that makes:

$$\gcd(97+r, 106-r) > 1\text{?}$$

Comment: Specifically, looking for something besides enumerating all possibilities until I find the answer.

Comment: Considering that it's equal to $\operatorname{gcd}(97 + r, 203)$, yes.

Comment: Excellent.  Could you elaborate on the technique, please?

Comment: @melodrama Have you heard about Euclid's algorithm? The complete algorithm fails in this case, because you can't go any further than that (you have the letter $r$ and are at the same time restricted to integers), but the steps are equally valid: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a+b)$ with fitting $a,b$.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur.  Do you know how to find the r without starting at 1 and iterating until you find the first value?  I mean, the answer is 1, but I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to do this in general.

Comment: Yes, there is. We have the prime factorisation $203=7\cdot29$, so we're looking for an $r$ that makes $97+r$ divisible by either one of those. We see that $97=7\cdot13+6$, so adding one more will do it.

Comment: OK, great - thanks!

Comment: If $r=1$ then you have $98$ and $105$, which are both obviously divisible by $7$. $\qquad$